Finding a ticker symbol's age in Pine
I'm trying to edit the Saty ATR Levels by adding a conditional statement that changes the timeframe (Trading Type) if the current tickerid is younger than 14 years (how long it takes to develop yearly ATR levels). I figured that it would be available under syminfo, but I haven't been able to find anything on it. Does anyone have any idea how you would determine a ticker's age?
I was thinking you could count how many bars a ticker has all-time, but I have no idea how to go about that.
Thanks in advance.
